# Using AmCharts to create bar chart from JSON object retrieved from localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, amcharts

I'm trying to create a bar chart using AmCharts using an array that is part of a larger JSON object that is being retrieved from localStorage.  Basically, what I do is retrieve the JSON string, parse it back to JSON object, search take the specific array I'm dealing with ("results"), search that array for the result I'm looking for (via "id"), and then take the array I need ("scores") from that specific result.  Then, I use that array as the input for the AmChart code.

I've tested the AmChart code with another sample array (defined in the code) and it works fine.  However, when I try to retrieve from localStorage, I am unable to get the chart to display.  Any thoughts as to why?  The code in question is here:

```
//retrieve initial results response from localstorage 
var search_results = localStorage.getItem("results_response"); 

//convert retrieved string back to JSON array 
var search_results_object = JSON.parse(search_results); //search_results_objects is now a JSON array 

var results = search_results_object.results; //pull out results array 

//get venue_id of detail page from local storage 
var ven_id = localStorage.getItem("country_id"); 

//search JSON response for venue ID 
var chartDataResults = []; 
var searchField = "id"; 
var searchVal = ven_id; 
for (var i=0 ; i < results.length ; i++) 
{ 
if (results[i][searchField] == searchVal) { 
    chartDataResults.push(results[i]); 
} 
}  

var chartDataInput = chartDataResults.scores; 

//this all works:
var chartData = chartDataInput; 

var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart(); 
chart.dataProvider = chartData; 
chart.categoryField = "country"; 
chart.rotate = true; 

var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph(); 
graph.valueField = "score"; 
graph.type = "column"; 
chart.addGraph(graph); 

var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis; 
categoryAxis.autoGridCount = false; 
categoryAxis.gridCount = chartData.length; 
categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start"; 
categoryAxis.labelRotation = 90; 
graph.fillAlphas = 0.8; 
chart.write('chartdiv');
```

Most recently, the dev console in Chrome has told me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".  The chart does not render, either.  Thoughts?  I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: make `JSFiddle` for your problem

Comment: i'm not sure how to pull in the JSON from localStorage into JSFiddle, etc

Comment: Could you try to debug and print out the values of search_results, search_results_object, results right after you assign them? At some point they become undefined...

Comment: re the fiddle, you could set the values of localStorage through javascript, [here is one example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xFtQR/23/)

Comment: same as in your site you can use in fiddle see the link provided by @ılǝ

Comment: you get in your code by this line `var search_results = localStorage.getItem("results_response"); ` same method in jsfiddle no difference and also same for savein like `localStorage.setItem("results_response",SOME_Data); `

Comment: after debugging based on what ılǝ said, it looks like everything is defined up until 'chartDataInput'.  what am I doing wrong there?  "scores" that i refer to here: `var chartDataInput = chartDataResults.scores;` is an array.  do i need to treat it differently when pulling it out?

Comment: :) `chartDataResults` is an array, not an object. chartDataResults.scores should be undefined

Comment: yes, so how do i handle it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails because of this:

```
var chartDataInput = chartDataResults.scores;
```

`chartDataResults` is an array by your declaration, not an object. According to the [amDocs](http://docs.amcharts.com/2/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart) you could pass `chartDataResults` directly, given that it is in the correct format, eg `[{title:"sample 1",value:130},{title:"sample 2",value:26}];`.

If so - try to replace:

```
var chartDataInput = chartDataResults.scores; 

//this all works:
var chartData = chartDataInput;
```

with

```
var chartData = chartDataResults;
```

If you chartDataResults array is not in the correct format, you need to construct it in that loop. Something like:

```
for (var i=0 ; i < results.length ; i++)  { 
  if (results[i][searchField] == searchVal) { 
    var aResult = new Object();
    aResult.title = results[i].title; // or results[i]['title']
    aResult.value = parseInt(results[i].value); // or results[i]['value']
    chartDataResults.push(aResult); 
  } 
}
```

I am speculating that in your json objects you have `.title` and `.value`. If not - replace them accordingly. If you're not sure :) what properties they have - print them to the console and inspect them.

Comment: if i do that, there are no errors, but the graph doesn't render.  chartDataResults is a single result of the search, and there is an array stored within that called "scores".  "scores" holds all of the data that needs to be charted.

Comment: the problem here i think is that i've defined chartDataResults as an array when it is really an object, and chartDataResults.scores is the array.

Comment: Actually according to the documentation your chartDataResults should be an array of objects. I will prepare a fiddle for that part in a second.

Comment: no, my code is bad.  what I need to really know is how to change the `search JSON response` section of my code to find an object and define it as such, rather than defining it as an array

Comment: because the object that it finds has a number of different name/value pairs, and one of those holds an array of objects (which is what i want to use with amcharts).  does that make sense?